# How to update XML attributes using Linq to XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a collection of custom objectswhich has storeid. I also have an XmlDocument which I query data from the database and constructed in memory. The StoreId property in the custome object corresponds to the "Value" object in the XML.I have to loop through my custom collection and match the StoreId to the "Value" attribute in the XML and set its "Checked" attribute equal to true. As shown in the XML below, all the "Checked" attribute values are set to false at the start.

```
<Tree>
<Node Text="Whole ">
  <Node Text="America">
     <Node Text="NewYork">
        <Node Value="28" Checked="false " Text="NY1" />
        <Node Value="29" Checked="false " Text="NY2" />
     </Node>
     <Node Text="Houston">
        <Node Value="13 " Checked="false " Text="H1" />
        <Node Value="14 " Checked="false " Text="H2" />
        <Node Value="16 " Checked="false " Text="H3" />
        <Node Value="19 " Checked="false " Text="H4" />
        <Node Value="26 " Checked="false " Text="H5" />
     </Node>
     <Node Text="GeorgeTown">
        <Node Value="21 " Checked="false " Text="G1" />
        <Node Value="23 " Checked="false " Text="G2" />
        <Node Value="25 " Checked="false " Text="G3" />
     </Node>
  </Node>
  </Node>
  </Tree>
```

My code is:

```
public class MyObject
 {
    public string StoreId { get; set; }
    public bool HasValue { get; set; }
 }

 Code to update XML:
 XmlDocument baseDocument = ConstructXMLFromDataBase();
 XmlNodeList dataNodes = baseDocument.SelectNodes("//Tree/Node/Node/Node");

 List<MyObject> myCollections = GetMyCollection();

 foreach (var myCollection in myCollections)
 {
    foreach (XmlNode node in dataNodes)
    {
      //code to update
    }               
 }
```

I believe it can be done easily with Linq to XML and I am very new to Linq to XML. Moreover most of the samples available on the internet are about updating XML loaded from a disc and not constructed in memory.

Thanks

Comment: Note that your XPath query is greedy. `//Tree/...` searches for all `Tree` tags. I think you meant `/Tree/...` which starts at the root.

Comment: That's because the "Value" attribute is present at the third level of the Node element. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish the update with your method by adding one more inner loop:

```
foreach (XmlNode checkedNode in node.ChildNodes)
{
    checkedNode.Attributes["Checked"].Value = "true";
}
```

If you want to use Linq, you should switch to XDocument:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);     //xml is a string, can be returned from a function, 
                                    //built dynamically, etc.

var nodesToUpdate = doc.Descendants("Node")
                       .Where(n => n.Attributes("Checked").FirstOrDefault() != null);

foreach (var node in nodesToUpdate)
{
    //TODO: check update conditions, etc.

    node.Attribute("Checked").Value = "true";
}
```

Comment: Hi CoolBots, thanks! Since the additional foreach loop turned out to be simpler, I have used it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want using LINQ to Xml you need change `ConstructXMLFromDataBase` method to return `XDocument` object.

```
XDocument document = ConstructXMLFromDataBase();
```

If you constructed xml from the string loaded from database you can use

```
return XDocument.Parse(validXmlString);
```

In case your xml is not valid document (without `<?xml..` tag) then you can return `XElement`

```
return XElement.Parse(yourXmlString);
```

Or use "dirty" workaround and convert it to `XDocument`

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = ConstructXMLFromDataBase();
XDocument document;
using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument))
{
    document = XDocument.Load(nodeReader);    
}
```

And then update existed nodes. This code will work in both cases, where `document is XDocument` or `document is XElement`

```
var storeIdCollection = GetMyCollection().Select(myObject => myObject.StoreId);
var storeIds = new HashSet<string>(storeIdCollection);

var nodes = document.Descendants.Where(node => node.Attribute("Value") != null);
foreach(var node In nodes)
{
    var storeId = node.Attribute("Value").Value;
    If (storeIds.Contains(storeId))
    {
        node.Attribute("Checked").Value = "true";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find  Linq2Xml + XPath easier to use

```
var id = "19";
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

xdoc.XPathSelectElement($"//Node[@Value='{id}']").Attribute("Checked").Value = "true";

xdoc.Save(filename);
```